# Hover effect jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I trying to do hover effect using following code. But its not working please help me

Script

```
$('.sha').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).next().children('div').css('display','block');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).next().children('div').css('display','none');
  })
```

HTML

```
<div class="listing_share_cont">
    <a href="#" class="sha">Share</a>
    <img src="images/listing_share_arrow_down.jpg" alt=" ">                 
    <div class="list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont">
        <div class="list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont_arrow">
            <img src="images/home_list_view_share_pop_arrow.png" alt=" " />
        </div>
        <div class="list_view_share_button_pop_up">
            <!-- Some images here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont { 
    float: left; left: 10px; position: absolute; top: 9px; width:285px; display:none;
}
.list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont_arrow {
    float:left; width:265px; margin:0 0 -4px 0;
}
.list_view_share_button_pop_up { 
    float:left; width:265px; background:#0474be; padding:8px 8px 4px 8px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Have you tried placing `console.log` or `alert` statements in the hover functions?

Comment: It would also help if you explain the desired effect as well as the current behaviour to give us a better idea of what you are trying to do...

Comment: `$(this).next()` is an `img`. It won't have any children. You need to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i want when user hover on share the <div class="list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont"> will display block

Answer (score 0):

The element you want to show is a sibling of the `.sha` element being hovered. You can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select that element (notice that you can use `show` and `hide` instead of `css`):

```
$('.sha').hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings(".list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont").hide();
});
```

From there, you can reduce the code to only one callback, which uses [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('.sha').hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".list_view_share_button_pop_up_cont").toggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .first() and nextAll to get what you want

```
$('.sha').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).nextAll("div").first().show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).nextAll("div").first().hide();
  })
```